# In iOS, how to save the current hour, minutes and seconds from current time into separate ints?

Tags: ios, datetime, ios5

In iOS, is it possible to save hours, minutes, seconds into different integer variables from the current time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
NSInteger seconds = [components second];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one representation:

```
CFGregorianDate date =
       CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), tz);
```

(How you intend to *save* that otoh…)